# How to call(back) a slider after div show()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a jquery slider (flexslider) on my page and I have 3 sliders. Two of them are in hidden divs with display: none;

When I now show() a div, the slider isn't loaded (slider is load in document.ready()).

How can I "callback" or re-call the slider functionality when I show the next div?

The Slider is loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",           
        directionNav: false,             
          controlNav:false,           
          keyboardNav:false,         
          direction: "horizontal",        
          slideshowSpeed:3000,       
          animationSpeed:600,        
          randomize: false     
        });
  });
</script>
```

This is how I change:

```
function changeSection(section) {
    if(activeSection != section) {
        $('#'+activeSection).fadeToggle("slow");
        $('#'+section).delay(500).fadeToggle("slow");

        $('#menu-'+activeSection).removeClass('active');
        $('#menu-'+section).addClass('active');

        document.title = activeSectionTitle;
        history.pushState({}, '', section);

        activeSection = section;
    }
}
```

Comment: @IonicăBizău See above or / http://pastebin.com/fLfZsE2C

Comment: Can you link the flexslider plugin you're using? Don't its docs state anything about callbacks?

Comment: They sadly don't have docs... http://www.code7.co.uk/joomla-responsive-slider